# Sliding RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in a `LinearLayout`. How can I have LinearLayout "slide" upwards until it hits the App Bar, whereby the `RecyclerView` should then begin scrolling the items as usual. Likewise, scrolling the list down will begin to "slide" the entire container down when the the first item is reached in the list until the container returns to its starting position.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/nearby_stops"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/half_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/half_padding"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I looked at https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel, however it does not support `RecyclerView` and the moment.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `RecyclerView` inside a `Fragment`, so make an XML like so for the `Fragment`:

**This is your XML for the RecyclerView**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/nearby_stops"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/half_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/half_padding"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then for the `Activity` hosting the `Fragment` just add a `FrameLayout` for the `Fragment`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Put other views here -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/slidingFragmentContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Then inside your `Activity` when you instantiate the `Fragment` do the following:

```
    SampleFragment listFragment = new SampleFragment();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom,
                    R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .add(R.id.slidingFragmentContent, listFragment)
            .commit();
```

The animations `R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom` and `R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom` are available in the Android API.

I also noticed you're not setting any orientation for your `LinearLayout`s. Set an orientation like so `android:orientation="..."`

You can assign a `Button` to show the `Fragment`, like so:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showFragment();
    }
});
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------

### To get the `RecyclerView` to scroll up as you scroll it just use the following:

Create an XML layout like this for your `Activity`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/map_view_height"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <YourCustomViewContainingTheMap
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Inflate your `Fragment` inside the `FrameLayout` and then as you scroll up it should do a parallax animation on the `Map`. If you don't want a `Parallax` effect just set `app:layout_CollapseMode="pin"`

### Here is a sample app I created, you can see as I scroll up on the `RecyclerView` it slides up:

[image]

(Please note the Frame Animations on GIFs is not that great)

To get a shadow behind the sliding list on your map, just set `app:layout_collapseMode` to `parallax` and then add another view in front of your `MapView` inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` which can be your mask, it can be be a simple view, and then you can adjust it's alpha value as you scroll up the list.

It's better to use the native android views at your disposal, I noticed that `AndroidSlidingPanelLayout` has around 43 issues.

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry I didn't mean a transition. But rather the RecyclerView slides when the user scrolls the list.

Comment: Oh that's not hard to solve at all, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer, see if it helps you out. If it does please accept my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it shortly.

Comment: Hey Andy, I think this is on the right track. You've given me some good ideas. One thing: how can I keep the `App Bar` and `TabLayout` pinned to the top like in my image?

Comment: Please make a separate question for that, link that here, and I'll answer it for you there. I believe I thoroughly I answered your question, please accept this answer if it satisfied the current question **Sliding RecyclerView**: "How can I have LinearLayout "slide" upwards until it hits the App Bar...".

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164081/collapsing-expanding-view-coordinated-with-sliding-recyclerview