# Collapsing/Expanding view coordinated with Sliding RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to achieve the following affect (also see image below):

- the app opens with a view (map) partially visible and the `RecyclerView` at a default anchor point (center image)
- user scrolls the `RecyclerView` up, the map collapses and the list continues scrolling (right image)
- user scrolls the `RecyclerView` down, the map expands to a maximum point (note the list should not slide completely off screen but to some anchored point) (left image)

[image]

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create this we need 1 `Activity` and 3 `Fragment`s.

The `Activity` will host a `TabLayout` and a `ViewPager` like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Since we only need to do the sliding behavior for the 1st `Fragment` the first `Fragment` gets an XML layout like so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can make the other `Fragment`s however you like I just created fake data and a simple `RecyclerView` in the other `Fragment`s.

Then call these views in your `Activity` and `Fragment` like so:

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SampleViewPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.another_activity);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPagerAdapter = new SampleViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

}
```

**ViewPager Adapter**

```
public class SampleViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SampleViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new MapFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ScrollFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ScrollFragment();
            default:
                return new ScrollFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String[] tabNames = {"Stops", "Planner", "Alerts"};
        return tabNames[position];
    }

}
```

**Map Fragment with Sliding RecyclerView**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

        initCollapsingToolbar(root);
        // Initialize map
        initFragment();
        return root;
    }

    private void initCollapsingToolbar(View root) {
        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.collapsingToolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cyan_500));
    }

    private void initFragment() {
        FakeDataFragment fragment = new FakeDataFragment();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, scrollFragment)
                .commit();
    }

}
```

You should get something like this then:

[image]

#### Setting the position:

You can programmatically collapse the toolbar (`CollapsingToolbarLayout`) using the following code:

```
public void collapseToolbar(){
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mFrameLayout.getLayoutParams();
    AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior) params.getBehavior();
    if (behavior != null) {
        behavior.onNestedFling(rootLayout, appbarLayout, null, 0, 10000, true);
    }
}
```

This means when the User first sees the map the map is partially collapsed to your Default State.

Comment: Thanks Andy, everything works great with one exception. This method starts with the map fully expanded (my left image), but the `RecyclerView` should be at a default position (my center image).

Comment: I have thoroughly answered your question, and your comment is out of scope for this question. Your question clearly states **Collapsing/Expanding view coordinated with Sliding RecyclerView** and does not mention anything regarding `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `AppBarLayout.Behavior` which is completely out of scope, nevertheless I answered your comment thoroughly. You can play around with AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior to adjust the position of your dependent view.

Comment: Would you be kind as to share the whole solution, @AndyRoid?

Answer (score 0):

**I Found Solution for Tabs in CoordinatorLayout**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                                                                          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:statusBarScrim="@null"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/isprofile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/profile_cover"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <com.root.findagame.utills.CircleImageView
                            android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/profile_pic" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/cpb_white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium_size"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtAge"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"

                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/cpb_white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small_size" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/cpb_white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small_size"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/cpb_white"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#7CC142"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="#7CC142"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/lightGrayColor" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/htab_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>






*Fragment*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dummyfrag_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dummyfrag_scrollableview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />

</FrameLayout>
```